# Collection <T> class location in the .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, generics

The `Collection <T>` class exists under the `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace. Why does it not exist under `System.Collections.Generic` instead?

Comment: mww thanks for thz improvement.  i m using my phone so it skeeped all this issues :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because:

> The System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace contains classes that can
>   be used as collections in the object model of a reusable library. Use
>   these classes when properties or methods return collections.

and `Collection<T>` can be used as a collection in the object model of a reusable library.

See
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.objectmodel(v=vs.110).aspx

The full explanation is here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2005/03/15/the-reason-why-collection-readonlycollection-and-keyedcollection-were-moved-to-system-collections-objectmodel-namespace/

(That appears to explain the *real* reason, if you ask me...)

Comment: Great catch!!!!

Comment: BTW what seems very obvious it's just a design decision. I mean, who returns `Collection<T>` instead of `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Yes, I agree.